# Trying to get my home button image directly to the left of my logout button

Tags: css, html

I can not get my home button image directly to the left of my logout button. I have changing the css all over. I also tried adding breaks and extra lines but that always gives an unexpected result. This is my HTML code.

```
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
    <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a">
    <h1>Add a New Subdiv file  <a href="/main" class="HomeButton">   
        <img src="../../../../Pictures/dwelling1.png" height="50"/></a>
            <a href="/logout" class="LogoutButton"> Logout </a></h1></td></tr>
```

This is my css code.

```
.HomeButton {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
.LogoutButton {
    text-align:center;
    width: 10%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#ffec64;
    border:2px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:.01% .1%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of anchor tags in the html.

try

```
<h1>Add a New Subdiv file  
   <a href="/logout" class="LogoutButton"> Logout </a>
   <a href="/main" class="HomeButton">   
        <img src="../../../../Pictures/dwelling1.png" height="50"/>
   </a>
</h1>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.HomeButton {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.LogoutButton {
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffec64;
  border: 2px solid #ffaa22;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .01% .1%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a">
    <h1>Add a New Subdiv file  
            <a href="/logout" class="LogoutButton"> Logout </a><a href="/main" class="HomeButton">   
        <img src="../../../../Pictures/dwelling1.png" height="50"/></a></h1>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm you need what you said you need just change your html like this `<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a">
    <h1>Add a New Subdiv file  <a href="/logout" class="LogoutButton"> Logout </a><a href="/main" class="HomeButton"><img src="../../../../Pictures/dwelling1.png" height="50"/></a></h1></td></tr>`